# how to install cocos2d-x v2.2.5 & create a new project on mac

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

```
i just downloaded Cocos2d-x Version 2.2.5,now i want to install
```

it's template in my Xcode plus i want to create sample new project 
but i searched a lot but i don't find single guidelines on how to 
create new project in this new version. Really need help in this.

```
i searched even on cocos2d-x forum but still no help . So please kindly help on this.in previous version we could install it this way.

To install the templates fire up a Terminal, navigate to the Cocos2D-x directory:

     cd $COCOS2DX_ROOT

In order to install the templates you need to have root privilege, so we will call:

     sudo ./install-templates-xcode.sh

But In this Version , i don't know how to do it & also having 
no idea on how to create a new project. please help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x 2.2.5 setup summary of the solution that worked for me :

-use the existing projects (helloworldCpp and TestCpp) or create a project using the supplied python script the {cocos2d_root}/tools/project-creator directory:
user$ python create_project.py -project AppTest -package com.appsomniacs.test -language cpp

-follow the instructions in the README.md that every new project has in it's {project root}/proj.android folder that is made with create_project.py

Note: I will recommend to use latest Cocos2d-x SDK i.e. 3.2 which is with awesome new features & better performance.

Thanks,
PriMachine